# Is there a URL that can be used for a “Share on Slack” button?

Tags: javascript, slack, slack-api

I'd like to put a "Share on Slack" button on my website. It would be similar to the buttons we have for "Share on Facebook" and "Share on Twitter". A user would click on it and be able to post some text and a link that we suggest on Slack.

I've been able to find URLs that I can use on Facebook and Twitter for doing this, but I've been unable to track down one for Slack? Does it exist? I see that AddThis was able to implement a button but I'm not sure exactly how they are doing it.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you could not find a "Share on Slack" button is that Slack is not a public community site like Facebook and Twitter, but consists of many closed groups. Think of it as closed Facebook groups that require approval to join. And each Slack team has a different internal structure, there is no "main feed" to share something on, but many channels with names defined by each team.

Consequently your "Share on Slack" button would need to first get authorization for each Slack team you want to share on, so each user would need to install your button (with its Slack app) to their Slack team. Its a cumbersome process and many users will probably not have permission from their admins to do so. Its technically possible though and will require you to create a Slack app with server-side coding to implement. Just a URL will not work.

Comment: @uthay if this answer helped you, please consider marking it as solution, so we can close this question. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the Answer ! by the way ,http://www.addthis.com/social-buttons/slack-button - this addthis plugin allows user to share on slack ..i have used it in my dashboard. only thing is i don't want this thing done through a 3rd party app like "addthis" , hence they'have proved that it is technically possible.

Comment: Interesting. thanks for sharing it. I will check it out, but by guess is it will require the user to install itself as a Slack app to work - as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken would you have some details of how it is possible to implement with server-side coding? I'm currently struggling to find informations about this!

Comment: Now that we have all slack teams on app.slack.com/client/{{team}}, this is technically possible.

Comment: @piyushkantm Interesting. Can you elaborate what exactly is new and how that enables what OP is asking?

Comment: The reason it was not possible earlier was because slack URLs were hosted like <team>.slack.com which would make it harder to give an api to share as it’d have to be team specific... but now since the app is hosted on app.slack.com, we can have an api like app.slack.com/share?text=something and there we can use team, and then channel and share text. Maybe slack would roll out those feature soon

Comment: It's certainly a possible feature. They already do this for their Android app. You select Slack to share to, and then the 'Share in Slack' page that's opened gives you options for the workspace and channel. Unfortunately, I can't find any evidence that they have implemented this via web links or deep links to the desktop app.

Comment: Perhaps this would help? https://api.slack.com/reference/deep-linking

Comment: Or this one (which requires creating a slack app though): https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks